# How can I remove incomplete kernel installation in Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, updates, synaptic

Using Ubuntu 16.10 on kernel 4.8.0-22 as it originally came when installed.

After kernel upgrade to 4.8.0-26, update is stuck. I still can boot my computer and using Ubuntu normally, but cant make upgraded completed.

I've read many articles about how to fix it as `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` but on terminal it doesn't let me do it (need `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and it goes stuck once more (I'm using driver 367.57 to my GTX 950). I tried also to open synaptic but as installation is incomplete it doesn't let me open it.

How can I figure it out?

Answer (score 4):

OP solved their own problem (edited into an answer from comments)

> I solved it using [this thread on Ubuntu
>   Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=843690)
>
> ```
> dpkg --get-selections >~/Desktop/bad-install 
> gedit ~/Desktop/bad-install
> ```
>
> erase the line(s) with the name of the program(s) that you couldn`t install properly from the file and
>   save it, then run:
>
> ```
>   sudo dpkg --clear-selections
>   sudo dpkg --set-selections <~/Desktop/bad-install
>   sudo apt-get -u dselect-upgrade
>   sudo update-grub
> ```
>
> And that`s all. Issue fixed. :)